# Why does subprocess getoutput add a non-constant overhead?

Tags: python, subprocess

In Python 3.6.7 on macOS, I ran this test to time `subprocess.getoutput`:

```
In [11]: %timeit for _ in range(100000): x = 1                                                                                                         
1.97 ms ± 48.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [12]: %timeit subprocess.getoutput('python -c "for _ in range(100000): x=1"')                                                                       
42.1 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [13]: %timeit for _ in range(1000000): x = 1                                                                                                        
19.3 ms ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [14]: %timeit subprocess.getoutput('python -c "for _ in range(1000000): x=1"')                                                                      
92.5 ms ± 3.19 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [15]: %timeit for _ in range(10000000): x = 1                                                                                                       
189 ms ± 4.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [16]: %timeit subprocess.getoutput('python -c "for _ in range(10000000): x=1"')                                                                     
551 ms ± 11.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [17]: %timeit for _ in range(100000000): x = 1                                                                                                      
1.94 s ± 51.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
In [18]: %timeit subprocess.getoutput('python -c "for _ in range(100000000): x=1"')                                                                    
5.25 s ± 26.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I was surprised to see that the time overhead for subprocess seems to scale with the time that the inner call takes. I would have expected the overhead to be roughly constant. Why is this the case? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `python` command you're running is the same Python version your IPython session is using?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica good question, yup, it looks that way: ```In [4]: import subprocess; subprocess.getoutput('python --version')                                                                                    
Out[4]: 'Python 3.6.7'```

Comment: Part of the difference is that your non-subprocess `timeit` is using function-local variables (due to how `timeit` sets up the timing loop), and function-locals are faster than globals.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks! I think that's probably the key. The difference seems to disappear if I time on the commandline instead of using timeit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @user2357112 supports Monica in the comments, the discrepancy seems to disappear if I use `time` in the commandline instead of `%timeit`, suggesting that the difference is in the access to the function-local variables.

```
$ time python -c "for _ in range(10000000): x=1"
real    0m0.592s
user    0m0.551s
sys 0m0.034s
$ time python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.getoutput('python -c \"for _ in range(10000000): x=1\"')"
real    0m0.644s
user    0m0.590s
sys 0m0.046s
$ time python -c "for _ in range(100000000): x=1"
real    0m5.104s
user    0m5.053s
sys 0m0.039s
$ time python -c "import subprocess; subprocess.getoutput('python -c \"for _ in range(100000000): x=1\"')"
real    0m5.161s
user    0m5.098s
sys 0m0.051s
```